# How to create a function import in odata (for fiori), that is created via cds view?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

I want to create a function import in odata for use in fiori, but everywhere it is written only how to create it through the SEGW transaction. Is there any way to create a function import for odata service, created via cds view?

Comment: You mixe here up some things. To write back you can add your CDS to a gateway projekt, use bopf or on haha 2020 use rap. Looking only at CDS, there is no write back feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create CDS view
2. add BOPF in eclipse
3. create action in eclipse for node in the bopf
4. Add the code to the "execute" method of the generated class
5. add annotation to odata.

The code for each step and screenshots are located in my another question:
[The function import is missing in the metadata of odata (odata created via CDS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69428613/the-function-import-is-missing-in-the-metadata-of-odata-odata-created-via-cds)