# The function import is missing in the metadata of odata (odata created via CDS)

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, cds

I want to create a function import in odata for use in sapui5 application. I create CDS view, add BOPF, create action SEND_MAIL, add annotation to odata. But function import tag is still missing in the metadata, i dont know why. And Exporting type in action inactive. Determination working, action not. What i do wrong?

СDS View:

```
@AbapCatalog.sqlViewName: 'ZGUT_FIORY_VW'
@AbapCatalog.compiler.compareFilter: true
@VDM.viewType: #COMPOSITE
@AbapCatalog.preserveKey: true
@AccessControl.authorizationCheck: #CHECK
@EndUserText.label: 'Test cds fiori list report'

// BOPF CRUD
@Metadata.allowExtensions: true
@ObjectModel:{
    modelCategory: #BUSINESS_OBJECT,
    compositionRoot: true,
    transactionalProcessingEnabled: true,
    createEnabled: true,
    updateEnabled: true,
    deleteEnabled: true,
    writeActivePersistence: 'ZGUT_TEST_UI5',
    semanticKey: ['id'],
    representativeKey: 'id'
}

@OData:{
    publish:true
}
@UI.headerInfo: {
     typeName      : 'Тестовое приложение fiori', // Заголовок списка
     typeNamePlural: 'Тестовое приложение fiori' ,
     title.value: 'Title', // Заголовок детальной страницы
     description.value: 'bukrs_txt'
}
@Search.searchable: true

define view ZGUT_CDS_FIORY as select from zgut_test_ui5
association [1..1] to t001 as _bukrs on zgut_test_ui5.bukrs = _bukrs.bukrs
association [0..*] to ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNT as _chartamount on zgut_test_ui5.curr = _chartamount.Curr
association [1..1] to ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNT as _chartamount2 on zgut_test_ui5.id = _chartamount2.Ids
{
    @UI.lineItem:[
        {position: 30},
        { type: #FOR_ACTION, dataAction: 'BOPF:SEND_MAIL', position: 1, label: 'Send mail' }
    ]
    @ObjectModel.mandatory: true
    key id as Id,
    
    // Another fields

}
```

BOPF:
[image: bopf]

Action:
[image: Action]

Action class:
[image: Action class]

Metadata (i dont see here any function import, i dont know why) /sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS/$metadata:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:sap="http://www.sap.com/Protocols/SAPData" Version="1.0">
<edmx:Reference xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Uri="http://host:50000/sap/opu/odata/IWFND/CATALOGSERVICE;v=2/Vocabularies(TechnicalName='%2FIWBEP%2FVOC_COMMON',Version='0001',SAP__Origin='LOCAL')/$value">
<edmx:Include Namespace="com.sap.vocabularies.Common.v1" Alias="Common"/>

</edmx:Reference>

<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="2.0">
<Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2008/09/edm" Namespace="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS" xml:lang="ru" sap:schema-version="1">
<EntityType Name="ZGUT_CDS_FIORYType" sap:label="Test cds fiori list report" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="Id"/>

</Key>

<Property Name="Send_mail_ac" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:label="Dyn. Action Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="6" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Номер"/>
<Property Name="Descr" Type="Edm.String" sap:label="Описание"/>
<Property Name="target_amount" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="6" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Количество"/>
<Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="255" sap:label="Заголовок"/>
<Property Name="Bukrs" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="БЕ"/>
<Property Name="bukrs_txt" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="25" sap:label="Название фирмы" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="Ab" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="0" sap:display-format="Date" sap:label="Дата начала"/>
<Property Name="Bis" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="0" sap:display-format="Date" sap:label="Дата конца"/>
<Property Name="Price" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="11" Scale="3" sap:label="Цена"/>
<Property Name="Curr" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Валюта"/>
<Property Name="Amount" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="6" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Количество"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_chartamount" Relationship="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_chartamount2" Relationship="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A"/>

</EntityType>

<EntityType Name="ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNTType" sap:semantics="aggregate" sap:label="ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNT" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="ID"/>

</Key>

<Property Name="ID" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
<Property Name="Ids" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="6" sap:aggregation-role="dimension" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Номер"/>
<Property Name="Amounts" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="6" sap:aggregation-role="measure" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Количество" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="target_amount" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="6" sap:aggregation-role="dimension" sap:display-format="NonNegative" sap:label="Количество"/>
<Property Name="Price" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="11" Scale="3" sap:aggregation-role="dimension" sap:label="Цена"/>
<Property Name="Curr" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="3" sap:aggregation-role="dimension" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Валюта"/>

</EntityType>

<Association Name="assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.ZGUT_CDS_FIORYType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A"/>
<End Type="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNTType" Multiplicity="1" Role="ToRole_assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A"/>

</Association>

<Association Name="assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.ZGUT_CDS_FIORYType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F"/>
<End Type="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNTType" Multiplicity="*" Role="ToRole_assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F"/>

</Association>

<EntityContainer Name="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS_Entities" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true" sap:supported-formats="atom json xlsx">
<EntitySet Name="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY" EntityType="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.ZGUT_CDS_FIORYType" sap:searchable="true" sap:content-version="1"/>
<EntitySet Name="ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNT" EntityType="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNTType" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1"/>
<AssociationSet Name="assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F" Association="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
<End EntitySet="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY" Role="FromRole_assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F"/>
<End EntitySet="ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNT" Role="ToRole_assoc_17D58845CCECEF801599D15F5569B65F"/>

</AssociationSet>

<AssociationSet Name="assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A" Association="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS.assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:deletable="false" sap:content-version="1">
<End EntitySet="ZGUT_CDS_FIORY" Role="FromRole_assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A"/>
<End EntitySet="ZGUT_CHART_AMOUNT" Role="ToRole_assoc_84AF2B5FF9693A0A2F011CFC2072B09A"/>

</AssociationSet>


</EntityContainer>

<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="self" href="http://host:50000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS/$metadata"/>
<atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="latest-version" href="http://host:50000/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZGUT_CDS_FIORY_CDS/$metadata"/>

</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by choosing the exporting type in the actions list and reactivate the bopf
[image]